# How to install gtest (googletest/gmock) on mac OS? The normal build setup didn't work

Tags: macos, googletest

The usual build setup of:

```
git clone https://github.com/google/googletest
cd googletest
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
make install
```

didn't work. macOS Mojave 10.14.6.  Getting a build error on the 'make' step.

```
/googletest-master/googletest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-port.h:844:12: error: 
          no member named 'make_tuple' in namespace 'std'
    using std::make_tuple;
          ~~~~~^
/googletest-master/googletest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-port.h:845:12: error: 
          no member named 'tuple' in namespace 'std'
    using std::tuple;
          ~~~~~^
/googletest-master/googletest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-port.h:965:3: error: 
          deleted function definitions are a C++11 extension [-Werror,-Wc++11-extensions]
      GTEST_DISALLOW_COPY_AND_ASSIGN_(GTestLog);
      ^
/googletest-master/googletest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-port.h:684:23: note: 
          expanded from macro 'GTEST_DISALLOW_COPY_AND_ASSIGN_'
      type(type const&) = delete;                 \
                          ^
/googletest-master/googletest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-port.h:965:3: error: 
          deleted function definitions are a C++11 extension [-Werror,-Wc++11-extensions]
/googletest-master/googletest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-port.h:685:34: note: 
          expanded from macro 'GTEST_DISALLOW_COPY_AND_ASSIGN_'
      type& operator=(type const&) = delete
etc
```

A quick search didn't find any obvious answers on Stack or googletest github.

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution.  Answer was:

```
git clone https://github.com/google/googletest
cd googletest
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=17
make
make install
```

Answer (score 1):

This is also available as a homebrew formula `googletest`, so:

```
brew install googletest
```

Answer (score 0):

Walkthrough....

```
brew install googletest
```

Check where the files are

```
brew ls -v googletest
```

I see lots of

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/googletest/1.14.0/include/gmock/internal/custom/README.md
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/googletest/1.14.0/include/gmock/gmock-function-mocker.h
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/googletest/1.14.0/include/gmock/gmock-more-matchers.h
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/googletest/1.14.0/include/gmock/gmock-cardinalities.h
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/googletest/1.14.0/include/gmock/gmock-spec-builders.h
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/googletest/1.14.0/include/gmock/gmock-nice-strict.h
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/googletest/1.14.0/include/gmock/gmock.h
```

And I also see the libraries in

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/googletest/1.14.0/lib/libgtest_main.a
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/googletest/1.14.0/lib/libgtest.a
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/googletest/1.14.0/lib/libgmock.a
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/googletest/1.14.0/lib/libgmock_main.a
```

So QT time...

I have a TestProject, for my *project* which is called **HowToJson** (yours will be different) - and it is setup like this

```
QT += testlib
QT -= gui

CONFIG += qt console warn_on depend_includepath testcase
CONFIG -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

PROJECT = "HowToJson"  #My Project in the SubDirs Project... yours will be different
GTESTVER = 1.14.0      #Would be cleaner using cmake

INCLUDEPATH += ../$${PROJECT}/ \
                /opt/homebrew/Cellar/googletest/$${GTESTVER}/include

LIBS += /opt/homebrew/Cellar/googletest/$${GTESTVER}/lib/libgmock.a

VPATH +=    ../$${PROJECT}/


HEADERS +=  qsojson.h
SOURCES +=  tst_test.cpp \
            qsojson.cpp
```

My **tst_test.cpp** is simply this

```
#include <QtTest>
#include <gmock/gmock.h>

// add necessary includes here
#include "qsojson.h"

class test : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    test();
    ~test();

private slots:
    void test_case1();

};

test::test()
{

}

test::~test()
{

}

void test::test_case1()
{
    QsoJson *qj = new QsoJson();
    Q_ASSERT(qj);
    QCOMPARE(1,1);
}

QTEST_APPLESS_MAIN(test)

#include "tst_test.moc"
```

Hope that is enough of a cookie cutter for someone ...